# add object to 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, computer-science

```
public class XO {
    private String name;
    private static int turn = 1;

    public XO(String name) {
        if (2 % turn == 0) {
            turn++;
            name = "X";
        }
        else {
            turn++;
            name = "O";
        }

    }
    //set method
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    //public void setTurn(int turn){
    //this.turn=0;
    //}
    //get method
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getTurn() {
        return turn;
    }

    public boolean equals(XO obj) {
        return name == obj.getName();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "You are " + name;
    }
}


import java.util. * ;

public class TicTacToeBoard extends Board {
    private int turnCnt;
    private XO[][] board;

    public TicTacToeBoard(int rows, int columns) {
        super(rows, columns);
        turnCnt = 0;
        this.board = new XO[rows][columns];
    }
    //set method 
    public void setBoard(XO[][] board) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                board[i][j] = board.getName();
            }
        }

    }
    //get methods
    public XO[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public int getTurnCnt() {
        return turnCnt;
    }
    //print board
    public void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            }

        }
    }
    //add X or O
    public boolean add(int r, int c) {
        XO[][] j = new XO[r][c];
        if (r > 2 && c > 2 || this.board.equals(j)) return false;
        else

        //setBoard(j);
        return true;

    }
    //check win
    public boolean win(XO a, XO b) {
        //player 1 wins
        if (board[0][0] == a && board[1][0] == a && board[2][0] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][1] == a && board[1][1] == a && board[2][1] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][2] == a && board[1][2] == a && board[2][2] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][0] == a && board[0][1] == a && board[0][2] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[1][0] == a && board[1][1] == a && board[1][2] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[2][0] == a && board[2][1] == a && board[2][2] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][0] == a && board[1][1] == a && board[2][2] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[2][0] == a && board[1][1] == a && board[0][2] == a) {
            return true;
        }
        //now player 2 wins
        if (board[0][0] == b && board[1][0] == b && board[2][0] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][1] == b && board[1][1] == b && board[2][1] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][2] == b && board[1][2] == b && board[2][2] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][0] == b && board[0][1] == b && board[0][2] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[1][0] == b && board[1][1] == b && board[1][2] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[2][0] == b && board[2][1] == b && board[2][2] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][0] == b && board[1][1] == b && board[2][2] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[2][0] == b && board[1][1] == b && board[0][2] == b) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return board[0][0] + "\t" + board[1][0] + "\t" + board[2][0] + "\n" + board[0][1] + "\t" + board[1][1] + "\t" + board[1][2] + "\n" + board[0][2] + "\t" + board[1][2] + "\t" + board[2][2];
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm doing an assignment about creative a tactictoe game in java.These are my code. The guide says XO class should hold information about an "X" or an "O" object.

The class should have two attributes: a name (which is a String “X” or “O”) and a static int variable that is either set to 0 or 1 (it should be initialized to 1). You will use this variable to determine which name to give the object when it is created (e.g., if it is 1, set the name to "X").

I'm not sure how to use the turn variable, and I know I should pass X O like 2 object to 2d array, but I'm a little fuzzy about how to pass the object into 2d array. And also i want to print a board like a blank matrix at first , but it always be 
[null null null,
 null null null
 null null null]

Any help will be appreciated .Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

> im not sure how to use the turn variable

The turn variable in XO constructor is keeping track of who's turn it is by checking 2 modulo (turn number). So if it's turn 1: then 2%1 is 1, so the name variable is set to 'O'. For turn 2: 2%2 == 0, name gets set to 'X'.  *This basically uses a simple mod test to check whether the turn is even or odd..*

> but I'm a little fuzzy about how to pass the object into 2d array

Is this your code? It seems like you know how to manipulate 2d arrays already. array[row][column]. Can you elaborate what part of passing the object into a 2d array you are having trouble with? In your setBoard function you may want to dynamically iterate based on the length of the rows and columns you declare when instantiating the TicTacToe class.

> And also i want to print a board like a blank matrix at first , but it always be [null null null, null null null null null null]

You can print a table-like output by just printing correctly in your iteration. Try changing your Board.toString() function to be something like this.

```
for(XO[] row : board){
        for(XO item : row){
            System.out.print(item.getName());
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
```

It should change the output to look something like -

XXX

XXX

XXX

Edit: if you want to be a blank matrix that isnt filled with nulls you are going to need to either instantiate all the instances of XO to a default value, OR you can just add in a test if statement to test whether the value is null and print a placeholder character.

Comment: i do not know how to add the x o object to the board. Is that like this public boolean add(int r,int c){
  XO [][]player = new XO[r][c];
  if(r>3&&c>3)
   return false;
  else
    xo[r][c]=player;
   //setBoard(j);
   turnCnt ++;
   return true;
  
 }